# How can you select value based on three horizontal and vertical criteria?

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to organize the data from a colleague by putting it all in one tab, rather than having a separate tab for each week. What I currently have is this, for each week we are tracking.

[image: ![0]

I would like to organize it as follows to make the analysis part easier:

[image: ![0]

Is there a function that can grab the data from the original tab to put it in the above-mentioned format?

I've tried using `SUMPRODUCT`, but it returns duplicate values after the first correct value.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Week of 11th March'!$B$2:$B$19=$E$1)*('Week of 11th March'!$A$2:$A$19=$B4)*('Week of 11th March'!$C$1:$N$1=$C4)*('Week of 11th March'!$C$2:$C$19))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, here it is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MQLFD1CsdTdW4dM6ko3x5CYVzfGhEIh6KnVjCer6iAY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: could you pls elaborate on what exactly are you after? you want only to reshape the initial dataset? or you want to create a template for future usage?

Comment: or you just want to fill F / M and Total columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete everything and paste this into **A2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN( , 1, "♠"&TEXT(
 FILTER('Week of 18th March'!A3:A20, 'Week of 18th March'!B3:B20="Female"), 
 "m/d/yyyy")&"♦"&TEXT('Week of 18th March'!C1:M1, "h:mm am/pm")&"♦"&
 QUERY('Week of 18th March'!A3:M20, 
 "select C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M where B='Female'", 0)), "♠")), "♦"),
 INDEX(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN( , 1, "♠"&TEXT(
 FILTER('Week of 18th March'!A3:A20, 'Week of 18th March'!B3:B20="Male"), 
 "m/d/yyyy")&"♦"&TEXT('Week of 18th March'!C1:M1, "h:mm am/pm")&"♦"&
 QUERY('Week of 18th March'!A3:M20, 
 "select C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M where B='Male'", 0)), "♠")), "♦"), , 3),
 INDEX(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN( , 1, "♠"&TEXT(
 FILTER('Week of 18th March'!A3:A20, 'Week of 18th March'!B3:B20="Total"), 
 "m/d/yyyy")&"♦"&TEXT('Week of 18th March'!C1:M1, "h:mm am/pm")&"♦"&
 QUERY('Week of 18th March'!A3:M20, 
 "select C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M where B='Total'", 0)), "♠")), "♦"), , 3)})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This works great! I was only interested in the female, male, and total columns, but your solution solves the problem even better. Thank you very much!